# How does construction of dynamic routes work in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was just checking out the example between components in react and saw an example [HERE](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions):

```
import React from "react";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

/* you'll need this CSS somewhere
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in;
}
*/

const AnimationExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route
      render={({ location }) => (
        <div style={styles.fill}>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => <Redirect to="/hsl/10/90/50" />}
          />

          <ul style={styles.nav}>
            <NavLink to="/hsl/10/90/50">Red</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/hsl/120/100/40">Green</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/rgb/33/150/243">Blue</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/rgb/240/98/146">Pink</NavLink>
          </ul>

          <div style={styles.content}>
            <TransitionGroup>
              {/* no different than other usage of
                CSSTransition, just make sure to pass
                `location` to `Switch` so it can match
                the old location as it animates out
            */}
              <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="fade" timeout={300}>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <Route exact path="/hsl/:h/:s/:l" component={HSL} />
                  <Route exact path="/rgb/:r/:g/:b" component={RGB} />
                  {/* Without this `Route`, we would get errors during
                    the initial transition from `/` to `/hsl/10/90/50`
                */}
                  <Route render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
                </Switch>
              </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    />
  </Router>
);

const NavLink = props => (
  <li style={styles.navItem}>
    <Link {...props} style={{ color: "inherit" }} />
  </li>
);

const HSL = ({ match: { params } }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      ...styles.fill,
      ...styles.hsl,
      background: `hsl(${params.h}, ${params.s}%, ${params.l}%)`
    }}
  >
    hsl({params.h}, {params.s}%, {params.l}%)
  </div>
);

const RGB = ({ match: { params } }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      ...styles.fill,
      ...styles.rgb,
      background: `rgb(${params.r}, ${params.g}, ${params.b})`
    }}
  >
    rgb({params.r}, {params.g}, {params.b})
  </div>
);
```

The user can click on the navigation to navigate between components:

```
<ul style={styles.nav}>
       <NavLink to="/hsl/10/90/50">Red</NavLink>
       <NavLink to="/hsl/120/100/40">Green</NavLink>
       <NavLink to="/rgb/33/150/243">Blue</NavLink>
       <NavLink to="/rgb/240/98/146">Pink</NavLink>
</ul>
```

What i don't understand is the below:

```
<TransitionGroup>
  {/* no different than other usage of
    CSSTransition, just make sure to pass
    `location` to `Switch` so it can match
    the old location as it animates out
*/}
  <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="fade" timeout={300}>
    <Switch location={location}>
      <Route exact path="/hsl/:h/:s/:l" component={HSL} />
      <Route exact path="/rgb/:r/:g/:b" component={RGB} />
      <Route render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
    </Switch>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

how are these routes dynamically coded, with the colons between ? like so: `/hsl/:h/:s/:l` what is this really doing ? and how is this valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand what parameters and queries are.

1. Queries

> Typical URL containing a query string is as follows:
>
> http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret
>
> When a server receives a request for such a page, it may run a
>   program, passing the query string, which in this case is, name=ferret
>   unchanged, to the program. The question mark is used as a separator,
>   and is not part of the query string.
>
> Web frameworks may provide methods for parsing multiple parameters in
>   the query string, separated by some delimiter. In the example URL
>   below, multiple query parameters are separated by the ampersand, '&':
>
> http://example.com/path/to/page?name=ferret&color=purple

These are the values attached to the end of the URL in order to pass additional information about the condition of the url.

2. Parameters

> URL Parameters are parameters whose values are set dynamically in a
>   page’s URL, and can be accessed by its template and its data sources.
>   This makes pages incredibly dynamic, enabling a single page to power
>   an endless number of views.

An example would be exactly as you have mentioned in your question.

In case of `<Route exact path="/rgb/:r/:g/:b" component={RGB} />` React Router looks for exact match of `/rgb/` that has three additional values separated by slashes and those values are accessible from the router as `this.props.match.params.[r or g or b]` so basically the colon tells the router that it is a parameter and it's variable and what comes after it is used as the key to retrieve those variables.